# passing function in dart flutter returing null

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i dont know what i did wrong here i converted a button to a class on it own and it stopped working it keep returning null and i dont know why. I have adjusted the code and the button class does not give any errors. Take a look at the code below

HERE IS MY BUTTON CLASS

```
class BottomButtonIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomButtonIcon({required this.buttonText, required this.ontap});
  final String buttonText;
  final Void Function() ontap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: ontap,
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(buttonText),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
          margin: kbuttomContainerMargin,
          color: kbuttomContainerColor,
          height: kbuttomContainerHeight,
          width: double.infinity,
        ));
  }
}
```

CALL BUTTON CLASS AND PASSING SETSTATE AND THEN NAVIGATOR.PUSH

```
  BottomButtonIcon(
              buttonText: 'CALCULATE',
              ontap: () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ResultPage()));
                });
              },
            ),
```

ERROR MESSAGE IS:
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Comment: When i correct a couple of lines in your code, I don't get any error... i corrected this line `final void Function() ontap;` and deleted these lines`margin: kbuttomContainerMargin, color: kbuttomContainerColor, height: kbuttomContainerHeight,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you misspelled your function declaration:

```
final Void Function() ontap;
```

I don't know what `Void` is but I believe it has something to do with c++ support, please don't quote me on that tho. It should actually be `void` with no capital letters:

```
final void Function() onTap;
```

sidenote, on flutter there is a type called `VoidCallback` that is an equivalent of `void Function()`, most flutter callbacks use it and you can use it aswell if you want:

```
final VoidCallback onTap;
```